# Retrieving data from MySQL using JDBC and storing it as JSONArray in file

Tags: java, json, jdbc

I retrieved some data from `MySQL` using `JDBC` and I want to store all the data in a `JSONArray` and write it into a file. Can someone help me?

I`m getting following error:

```
"Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must
 start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]"
```

In code:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM quizQuestionAnswerGeneral, quizAnswerGeneral, quizQuestionGeneral "
                + "WHERE quizQuestionAnswerGeneral.idQuestion = quizQuestionGeneral.id "
                + "AND quizQuestionAnswerGeneral.idAnswer = quizAnswerGeneral.idAnswer;";
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String id = rs.getString("id");
            String idQuestion = rs.getString("idQuestion");
            String answerText = rs.getString("answerText");
            String correct = rs.getString("correct");
            String questionText = rs.getString("questionText");

            System.out.println("id: " + id);
            System.out.println("idQuestion: " + idQuestion);
            System.out.println("answerText: " + answerText);
            System.out.println("correct: " + correct);
            System.out.println("questionText: " + questionText);
            System.out.println("*----------------------------------------*");

            JsonObject obj = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("id", id)
                    .add("idQuestion", idQuestion)
                    .add("answerText", answerText)
                    .add("correct", correct)
                    .add("questionText", questionText)
                    .build();

            String jArray = obj.toString();

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jArray);
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\i5\\Desktop\\Json.txt");

            while (jsonArray.iterator().hasNext()) {
                file.write(jsonArray.toString());
            }
            System.out.println("Succes!");

            file.flush();
            file.close();
```

Comment: your "obj" is an object not an array of objects, then your trying to convert it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing different Json libs since you have JSONArray instead of JsonArray.
Try the following:

```
JsonArray jsonArray = Json.createArrayBuilder()
    .add(obj)
    .build();
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this, thanx!

Answer (score 0):

You should create JSONArray object outside of first loop and fill it with values inside loop for every row from ResultSet.

Comment: I created it outside, but it takes a very long time to compile, it`s benn 10 minutes since I ran the program and it still showing the results from the database and there are not that much data inside. Something is not working as it should, but thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for something simple like:

1. Build your object inside the while loop instead of getting a bunch of strings;
2. Add the created object to a list;
3. Use a parser like Gson/Jackson to create your json String, which will correctly build you a json array.

Right now you are trying to create a bunch of json arrays inside a while loop. The correct approach would be to create a bunch of JsonObject, and after the while loop add them to the JsonArray.

Comment: I need to learn how to use Gson, you`re not the first person to recomand it, thanx!

Comment: @VoicuMihaiCatalin You literally have to just use `gson.toJson(list)` to get what you need from the above example.